# Difference between `form.validate_on_submit()` and `form.validate()`

Tags: python-3.x, validation, flask-wtforms

What is the difference between `form.validate_on_submit()` and `form.validate()`?

In the [Flask WTF docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html), the author uses `form.validate_on_submit()`. The code works. When I substitute `form.validate_on_submit()` with `form.validate()`, I see no difference in behavior. I couldn't find `form.validate_on_submit()` in the source, but I managed to find `form.validate()` [code](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/form.py#L122).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`validate_on_submit()` is a shortcut for `is_submitted() and validate()`.

From the [source code](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/0598f96f70a695d5f84c05a9f4e11feff1d64caa/flask_wtf/form.py#L89), line 89, `is_submitted()` returns True if the form submitted is an active request and the method is POST, PUT, PATCH, or DELETE.

Generally speaking, it is used when a route can accept both GET and POST methods and you want to validate only on a POST request.