# "Not a valid choice" in SelectField Only After Adding Bootstrap

Tags: python, bootstrap-4, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm trying to build a very basic app in Flask: a single form that accepts a few inputs from the user (I'm brand new to web development). I was able to get it up and running initially, but when I tried to modify the HTML to include Bootstrap, I get a `Not a valid choice` error when clicking my submit button.

**Main app:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, session, redirect, url_for, request
from forms import CustomAnalyticsMenu

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/custom_analytics_menu', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def custom_analytics_menu():
    form = CustomAnalyticsMenu()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("validated_on_submit")
        session['menu_item'] = form.menu_item.data
        return redirect(url_for('submission'))

    else:
        print(form.errors)

    return render_template('custom_analytics_menu.html', form=form)

@app.route('/submission', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submission():
    return render_template('submission.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Form:**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, RadioField, SelectField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class CustomAnalyticsMenu(FlaskForm):
    menu_item = SelectField('Menu Item:', choices=[('option_one', 'Option One'),
                                                    ('option_two', 'Option Two'),
                                                    ('option_three', 'Option Three')])
    generate_deck = SubmitField('Generate deck')
```

**HTML:**

This is the HTML code that works:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div>
  <form method="POST" action="">
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

      {{ form.menu_item.label }} {{ form.menu_item }}

      {{ form.generate_deck() }}
  </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

However, when I change this portion:

`{{ form.menu_item.label }} {{ form.menu_item }}`

To this: (which I got from here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="menu_item">{{ form.menu_item.label }}</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="menu_item">
    {% for item in form.menu_item.choices %}
        <option>{{ item[-1] }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

My `SelectField` functionally looks the same (except obviously it has the Bootstrap styling), but now when I click the submit button, nothing happens and I get the error `Not a valid choice`. This is a snippet of what I'm trying to do, I also have a `RadioField` and a `StringField` but I get the same errors for those as well when trying to apply similar styling. Can someone help me understand where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out! I saw another StackedOverflow question ([Why is my flask form validation returning Not a valid choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46271433/why-is-my-flask-form-validation-returning-not-a-valid-choice)) and they had a `name` field in their `<select>`. I updated my (value, label) pairs so they matched (i.e. `('Option One', 'Option One')` rather than `('option_one', 'Option One')`) and updated the code to this:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="menu_item">{{ form.menu_item.label }}</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="menu_item">
        {% for item in form.menu_item.choices %}
          <option>{{ item[-1] }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
  </div>
```

It worked! Alternatively, I could have left the (value, label) pairs the same and used the code from SuperShoot's answer above. I can't say I fully understand *why* the `name` tag was needed, so if anyone has an explanation for that, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Yeah, the `name` attribute is needed as the value of the field is keyed to that name in the mapping that represents the form which is sent to the server. I should have picked that up along with your other error. The thing with the `value` attribute of the option tag is that it usually will be set to the value of a primary key representing a row in a database table. In that case the value would be `1` while the label would be `'Option One'`. Anyway, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

*Edited to include `name` attrib on `<select>` field as resolution of additional issue and further explained in @RaghavPaliwal's answer.*

The `choices` that you pass to the `SelectField` are a [a sequence of (value, label) pairs](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField).
In your example these are:

```py
[('option_one', 'Option One'), 
 ('option_two', 'Option Two'), 
 ('option_three', 'Option Three')]
```

The first element of those tuples is the actual value that the option represents and is meaningful in terms of your application. It needs to be set as the `value` attribute of the `<option>` tag. The second element in each tuple is just a nicely formatted representation of the value that the option represents for display to the user.

So, you need to provide a `value` attribute to each of your `<option>` tags:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="menu_item">{{ form.menu_item.label }}</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="menu_item" name="menu_item">
    {% for val, text in form.menu_item.choices %}
        <option value="{{ val }}">{{ text }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

If you don't provide a `value` attribute to your `<option>` tags, the content of the tag will be passed as the value of the form field instead. In your case this means that if `'Option One'` was selected, the string `'Option One'` would be passed as the value of the field. The form validation then tests that it is included in one of the choices values, `'option_one'`, `'option_two'`, or `'option_three'`, so the validation fails.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately, this didn't work and I'm still getting the same `Not a valid choice` error :(

Comment: I also tried making the value and label the same (so that even if it defaulted to the label it would be okay) but that didn't work either

Comment: I think I figured it out! See my comment below.