# How is this variable referenced before it is assigned?

Tags: python, flask

Error message: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'post_title' referenced before assignment

I tried using global before the variable, which resulted in a syntax error.

Relevant code:

```
class PostForm(Form):

    title = StringField('Title', [validators.Length(min=1, max=200)])

    body = TextAreaField('Body', [validators.Length(min=30)])

@is_logged_in
@app.route('/add_post', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add_post():
    form = PostForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():

        post_title = form.title.data
        body = form.body.data
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO posts(title, body, author) 
         VALUES(%s, %s, %s)',(post_title, body, session['username']))
        mysql.connection.commit()

        print(post_title)
        cur.close()
        flash('Post created', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    return render_template('add_post.html', form=form)
```

[image: Traceback]

Comment: It seem the indents are in mess, you should reformat the code.

Comment: Your indentation is wonky. *At a guess* , `if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():` has to be `True` before `post_title` exists currently. If the `if` check is not true, you never define `post_title` but again, you need to fix indentation to be sure of this.

Comment: Shoot my fault. It's not like that in the code. Ill edit.

Comment: What happens if you commend the cur.execute line and just do the print(post_title) ?

Comment: `cur.execute(...)` is definitely indented to be inside the `if` block in your actual code?

Comment: Yea I tried that and get the same error.

Comment: Yes definitely in the if block.

Comment: And you haven't fixed a typo without knowing it while writing this up as a question e.g. in `post_title = form.title.data`? I can see no other reason for the error.

Comment: I messed around with the spacing, got some unindent errors, not getting a value error, so I guess the spacing is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are misplacing the validation check. The form will have the values only when they are submitted via POST request. Give it a try:

```
@is_logged_in
@app.route('/add_post', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add_post():
    form = PostForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            post_title = form.title.data
            body = form.body.data
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO posts(title, body, author) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)',\
                        (post_title, body, session['username']))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            cur.close()
            flash('Post created', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        else:
            flash("Form validation failed")
    return render_template('add_post.html', form=form)
```

N.B.: A good answer on [Difference between `form.validate_on_submit()` and `form.validate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002323/difference-between-form-validate-on-submit-and-form-validate)